# JBoss Cache Cluster Issue

Tags: caching, jboss, jboss-cache

In our production environment we have three JBoss servers loadbalanced for application requests, client applications session has been maintained JBoss-cache with clustered enabled to make sure that all three servers should get the session object. All went fine in production for the past three months and it was very consistent. All of the sudden for the last one week we have an issue with cache replication and buddy backup listing.

Following are the issues creeped recently.

1. Replication between identified servers stopped suddenly.
2. Buddy_BACKUP list getting removed automatically.

We are running with JBoss Cache and JGroups in UDP mode. We couldnt trace any logs related to this events, please advise what could be the cause.

Since this issue is not resolved, we are planning to migrate this to TCP mode will that solve such discrepancy. Please advise. 12:45 
please revise the forumn question

Jboss Version : 4.2.2 GA

JDK : 1.6

JBoss Cache : 1.4.1